# Strava alamofire token

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, alamofire, strava

I'm adding Strava to an iOS application, Strava uses Auth2.0, every Strava API call needs a token to prove the user is authenticated and the app has permission to access the API. After obtaining a special "code" from user login response, I need to exchange it with Strava to get a token. I try to retrieve the token using the "code" I got from the login like this:

```
    var headers : HTTPHeaders {
            get {
                return [
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                ]
            }
        }

        let par = 
["client_secret": "671333e8c4a7726a5160adb615b74a428535f86e",
"client_id": "32573",
"code": "4/7wAZ8rA_jMXwponVhwGKuPmCDP4UGuCViojCq-K5KRiZ1CI1Gzqc2TdglTJ7k1DU2wIxH22fNguNNXTfIGpaD8g"] as [String : Any]

        Alamofire.request("https://www.strava.com/oauth/token", method: .post, parameters: par, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
            print("Response -> \(response.debugDescription)")
        }
```

The problem is that I always get a 400 Bad request, if anyone have experience with the Strava API or any idea of what I'm doing wrong please advise.

Comment: Same is happening for me. Let me know if you found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify `grant_type=authorization_code` to tells the token endpoint that the application is using the [authorization code grant type](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type):

```
https://www.strava.com/oauth/token?
    client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>&
    client_secret=<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>&
    code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE_FROM_STRAVA>&
    grant_type=authorization_code
```